# pip is successfully installing h2o4gpu, still getting 'ImportError: No module named h2o4gpu'

Tags: python, pip, h2o, h2o4gpu

I am attempting to install the h2o4gpu Python module as per the instructions listed here: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o4gpu/issues/464

pip says that it successfully installed all packages, including h2o4gpu-0.1.0.

However I then still get

```
    import h2o4gpu
ImportError: No module named h2o4gpu
```

and

```
kevin@Ubuntu-XPS:~/Downloads$ pip show tensorflow-gpu
Name: tensorflow-gpu
Version: 1.9.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: grpcio, mock, protobuf, enum34, gast, wheel, absl-py, backports.weakref, termcolor, six, numpy, tensorboard, setuptools, astor
kevin@Ubuntu-XPS:~/Downloads$ pip show h2o4gpu
kevin@Ubuntu-XPS:~/Downloads$
```

thus showing that pip acknowledges that `tensorflow-gpu` is installed, but not `h2o4gpu`.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 - could the cause of this be that h2o4gpu isn't yet supported on version 18? `import h2o` works fine.

Comment: Did you use the `pip3 install h2o4gpu-0.1.0-py36-none-any.whl` from the instructions you have linked?

Comment: Yes I did. If I try to use just `pip` I get `h2o4gpu-0.1.0-py36-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: Now that you pointed that out, `pip3 show h2o4gpu` does return all of its details. What does this mean? Is my program with `import h2o4gpu` attempting to run it using python2 or something?

Comment: You isntalled h204gpu for python3 but try to import it in python2 which doesn't work

Comment: I see, thank you. I am running the program within Atom using the 'script' plugin - it seems to automatically use python2 when it can. Running it manually with python3 from the command line works.

Comment: For Atom, see [this discussion](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-can-i-switch-python-version-for-script/24036/4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing python2 and python3. What you are using when running `pip` or `python` are all python2.7 (see also the output of `pip show tensorflow` where it is referring to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`).

The library you are trying to use only has `.whl` for python 3.6 (note the `py36` in the `.whl` files name)

Therefore, you need to either:

- Switch to using `pip3` and `python3`
- Find another library that works with python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

We are not shipping python 2.7 wheels for H2O4GPU, so you will need to use pip3 as suggested by FlyingTeller.

It would be best to use virtualenv to create a python environment to cause minimal changes to system python.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
virtualenv -p python36 h2o4gpuenv
. h2o4gpuenv/bin/activate
pip install h2o4gpu-*.whl
```

Now in this same virtual environment, start `python` and try `import h2o4gpu`.